# Node.js performance and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I faced some node.js memory weirdness, with react prerendering app. Here is memory profiling via newrelic:

[image: Memory stats via newrelic]

As you can see – once in an hour GC is freeing memory, when it comes up to 1GB. Is this okay for node.js (v0.12.x) or is something going wrong?

P.S. I read about newrelic's memory leaks, but turning it off provides the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not nodeJS, it is **v8** JS engine.

As far as I know, by **#perfmatters** talks, these issues (memory/performance) related to javascript can be made better by writing the application which takes **more care while allocating new objects**.

Here are some useful resource

[Youtube: talk by colt McAnlis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWmzxyMf2cE)

[Node.js Performance Tip: Managing Garbage Collection](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-garbage-collection/)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this looks normal. Without further investigating you'd expect rather short lived, more extreme peaks if it would have been memory leeks. Maybe read up on this [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)